# My download function for images from a database is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file upload which uploads the images to the database and this works fine however my download isn't working and there is no error popping up and im unsure why it isn't working. My database table is as follows id,image, image_name and image being a blob.

This is my download code:

download.php

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stat = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM image_centre where id=?");
    $stat->bind_param('i',$id);
    $stat->execute();
    $data= $stat->fetch();

    $file = 'images/'.$data['image_name'];

    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-Description: '.$data['description']);
        header('Content-Type: '.$data['type']);
        header('Content-Disposition: '.$data['disposition'].'; image_name="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: '.$data['expires']);
        header('Cache-Control: '.$data['cache']);
        header('Pragma: '.$data['pragma']);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;


    }

}
```

Below is the button which im linking the download.php to

```
<td><a href="includes/download.php?id=<?php $IID?>" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What is the response from the server?  Are the headers what you expect?  The content length?  What are the debugging details?  Have you checked your PHP logs for errors/warnings?

Comment: @David when i click the download button a blank screen appears ive noticed in the url it goes ..../download.php?id=   nothing ?  apart from that my debugging experience isnt that proficient

Comment: Looks like the problem has nothing to do with the download functionality.  You forgot to put the keyword `echo` in the link to output the `$IID` value.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what's wrong, you could (for debugging)

1. Run includes/download.php?id=xx directly in your browser, i.e. http://yourdomain.xx/includes/download.php?id=20 (find an ID from your DB you know works)
2. Add else statements to the if's and print out some debugging info, like for instance:

```
if(file_exists($file)){
   // Your code
}
else {
   print "The file does not exist there";
}
```

3. Check if you actually got some data from $data, like

```
if (is_array($data = $stat->fetch())) {
   // Record found, check if file exist and send file...
}
else {
   print "No record found";
}
```

Basically, figure out where it fails...

Comment: so basically the file doesnt exist there however i can't figure out why

Comment: I would 1) check directly on the server with a FTP client or similar if the file is actually there, 2) if the filename (image_name) in the database is exactly the same as on the server (avoid spaces and strange chars to save you a lot of trouble), 3) if the file path is actually correct (should be in a folder called image in the same folder as the script). You could also check file permissions on the server (if it's readable).